# Difference between the Gridview and Datagrid in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am new to asp.net. what is the difference between the Gridview and Datagrid in Asp.net

Thanks
sivakumar

Comment: At MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05yye6k9.aspx

Answer (score 1):

With .net framework 1.0 & 1.1 it was DataGrid control. In .net framework 2.0 and later it is GridView.

Answer (score 0):

The GridView control has a number of new features and advantages over the DataGrid control, which include:

- Richer design-time capabilities.
- Improved data source binding capabilities.
- Automatic handling of sorting, paging, updates, and deletes.
- Additional column types and design-time column operations.
- A Customized pager user interface (UI) with the PagerTemplate property.